Object Follow Curves Rotation (Geometry Nodes)
I want to make an object that is being distributed along a curve, follow the curves rotation. I've attached a screenshot of how I thought it needs to be setup, using a curve tangent, but its not working. The red cones are all going in the same direction.
Can anyone help? Thanks!


First hint: if you can use distribute points, your input is a "mesh", not a curve. So it doesn't have a curve tangent

Since your object is a "mesh", not a "curve", you can't use curve tangent (it doesn't exist).
You can use the "normal" of the points instead, but there are more variables involved, so the result might not be exactly what you expect:

You can connect the rotation from the distribution or not, the results vary a little, but are still "following" the curve.

If you want to use a curve, without randomness and evenly spaced, you can try this:


And if you want some randomness, some hacking is necessary (unless someone teaches me how to distribute points on curve).
Use the seeds to vary the random count and the random positions.

Quick explanation:

Create one point just to sample a random integer (which will be the random point count to distribute)
Create N points (using the random count)
Use these N points to sample random floats between 0 and 1 (they will be factors to sample positions and tangents on the curve)
Sample the curve with those factors to get: random position on the curve with their respective tangents


Thank you for your help. It wasn't exactly what I was going for, but I appreciate your time.
